# how to do conditional validation in angularjs and ngmessages?

Tags: angularjs

In my form i got a dropdown  with Yes / NO option , when user selects yes additional input box will be displayed and allows user to enter some value input box.

how can i validate input box using angularjs ngmessages only if it is visible or value in dropdown is 'Yes'?

html code

```
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                    <select ng-model="userAvailable">
                                        <option value="no">No</option>
                                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input ng-show="userAvailable == 'yes'" placeholder="If yes , add name?" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show the code that you already have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`.  `ng-show` removes it from the DOM so the validation doesn't execute on it.  `ng-show` just hides it.

```
<input ng-if="userAvailable == 'yes'" placeholder="If yes , add name?" type="text" class="form-control" />
```